# Selected value in selectbox Is not set angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to set a default selected value In an selectbox:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-init="selectedSupercustomer = superkundOptions[5]" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)">
```

Here Is my angular:

```
$scope.superkundOptions = [{ id: 5, namn: 'Halmstad Bågen / Pilen' }, { id: 6, namn: 'fisk Bågen / Pilen' }];
```

This don't work. The first row Is still empty.

Comment: I think you should do this `ng-init="selectedSupercustomer = superkundOptions[0]"` .As in the array superkundOptions ,there is no element at 5th position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bug

Your array have only two items, So you can't put index higer than one

### Solutions

**Option 1**

You need to change `ng-selected` instead of `ng-init` and also need change the *array index*

```
<select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-selected="superkundOptions[0]" ng-
model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in  
superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)">
```

**Option 2**

You don't need ng-init and ng-selected, just handle this problem in your controller side for assign your array item to the model value

*Controller code*

```
$scope.superkundOptions = [{ id: 5, namn: 'Halmstad Bågen / Pilen' }, { id: 6, namn: 'fisk Bågen / Pilen' }];

 $scope.selectedSupercustomer=$scope.superkundOptions[0]// **put 0 or 1 only**
```

*Html code*

```
<select class="form-control input-sm2"  ng-
    model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in  
    superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put it via your controller instead of ng-init

**controller**

```
$scope.selectedSupercustomer = $scope.superkundOptions[5];
```

**JS**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item as item.namn for item in superkundOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)">
```

In your example, the `superkundOptions` array contains only 2 items and you are trying to get the fifth.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out this fiddle

```
<select></select>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFCzV/34/)